# How can I insert my data into two different tables in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

Hi I'm new in using MySQL, I would like to insert my data into two different tables, I don't know how to do it using a query. All I know from now is how to insert multiple data in one table.

My input Data in 5 textboxes were

```
textbox1 = Garcia  (to be inserted in table1)
textbox2 = Michael (to be inserted in table1)
textbox3 = David   (to be inserted in table1)
textbox4 = 24      (to be inserted in table2)
textbox5 = 8888888 (to be inserted in table2)
```

My table fields looks like this

```
Table1
Last Name
First Name
Middle NAme

Table2
Age
Contact No.
```

Comment: Ive tried using 2 INSERT INTO but it didn't work

Comment: You were on the right track.  Add the code for both attempts to your question and elaborate on the didn't work part.

Answer (score 1):

Since you've not specified a UI language I'm assuming that you simply want the [SQL commands](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html) to do this.

```
INSERT INTO Table1  (`Last Name`, `First Name`,`Middle NAme`) 
             VALUES ("Garcia","Michael", "David");

INSERT INTO Table2  (`Age`, `Contact No.`) 
             VALUES (24, 8888888);
```

You've used bad table field names though. If this isn't working it is because you should remove periods and spaces from them all.

Also, it looks like you are just playing around but if you were being serious you'd want to include all of this information in one table and give that table a good name and an ID field.

Answer (score -3):

I agree with with first answer you can have as many insert statement as you need if you are using SQL Server you need to add the word go between statements

Comment: The question is tagged MySQL and even if it were sql server, you do not need the word go between statements.